# Looking for a freeware that helps training english vocabulary?

Tags: mac, language

I'm looking for a Free-ware on Mac OS X.6 that helps improving English vocabulary, very simply, for example by giving a word in another language (German or French would be perfect) and asking for the translation. It doesn't have to be a nice design or stuff, just simple and efficient. If anyone knows something like that, please let me know!!

EDIT: I'm looking for some kind of "evaluating program", something that tests your vocabulary, not a translator. Maybe I didn't make my question clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add vocab yourself, which I think will always be more valuable due to exposure when inputting lists of vocab, you need [jMemorize](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmemorize/).  Since it is a JAR file, you could do what I am working and use a portable Java VM and run it, along with your vocab lists, on a USB stick and backup everything online too.  I would say it is a pretty good bang-for-your-buck solution.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Could you just help me to make it work? What are the steps of the installation? Thank you. R.

Comment: You have Mac OS X, so this should be really, really simple. 1) Download the jMemorize application [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmemorize/files/jmemorize/1.3.0/jMemorize-1.3.0.jar/download). When it is done downloading, double-click the file (it will look like a piece of paper with a coffee cup, and say JAR at the bottom).  This will start the program. To add a new item, click the *Add card button*.  When you are done, click the *Save* button next to it to save your first group of flashcards.  Test yourself accordingly when done.

Comment: Thanks! Great! It looks like what I was looking for... Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There's [Babylon for Mac](http://www.babylon.com/mac), but it's not freeware.  The [online version](http://translation.babylon.com/) is free.

You could also try the free web based [Babelfish](http://uk.babelfish.yahoo.com/) or [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/).

[TranslateIt](http://mac.gettranslateit.com/) is not free, but it is not that expensive.